# how to SSH into Raspberry pi with iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ssh

I like to make an app to control my Raspberry Pi. I have to SSH to my Pi, I am using `ssh pi@192.XXX.X.XX` to SSH to my Pi via my Mac, after this I have to type in the password of my Pi. I like to creat this for my iPhone, I am using `system("ssh pi@192.XXX.X.XX");` to SSH into my Pi, but I obviously have to type in the password, but I dont know how. Does someone know how to incloude the password int the `system` command?

Comment: Is your phone jail broken?

Comment: @ErwaySoftware Yes, it is jailbroken, but my iPad is not jailbroken, it should be usable for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SSH Wrapper library for this, e.g. [libssh2-for-iOS](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS). It will enable you to use `connectToHost:port:user:password:error:`
`